# How do I bypass Login required for a few public pages in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine web application with roughly a hundred pages.  I need to restrict access to all but 5 of these pages to people who are logged in.

I know that in the app.yaml file I can add:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
  login: required
```

But this will require login for all pages.

Is there a way to specify not required, something like this (I am a newbie to GAE and Python):

```
- url: /public/.*
  script: main.app
  login: not required
```

Or is the only way to add a level to every reference for the restricted pages (the many hundreds of references to the restricted pages).  Something like:

```
- url: /restricted/.*
  script: main.app
  login: required

- url: /public/.*
  script: main.app
```

If this is the only way, can both still point to the same main.app?

What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 9):

The app.yaml handler entries are processed sequentially so you could have in your app.yaml something like the following:

```
- url: /(publicpage1|publicpage2|publicpage3).*
  script: main.app

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  login: required
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This would work well if the majority of pages were public and a few required login.  In this case, hundreds of pages require login and only a handful are public.  I don't want to have to individually list each of the hundreds of pages that require login (basically, the entire site requires login except for the few pages that explain why and how to request an account).

Comment: Sorry I read it the other way around, see my edited answer for the right answer.

Comment: @BillG. consider accepting the answers if they are useful to you.